# How effective is a Linux mdadm RAID 1 against silent data corruption?

Tags: hard-disk, raid, mdadm, software-raid, corruption

Assuming I've stored an image file on a regular hard drive. Years later, I may not be able to fully display this image file because of a hardware error.

Would a Linux RAID 1 disk array created with mdadm be resistant to such an error or will instead both drives contain the wrong information?

Or, is a Linux RAID only effective against a total hardware failure or somehow able to detect and fix small erorrs as well?

Comment: Against _silent_ data corruption you need RAID 5 or 6.

Comment: Are you aware of a solution that doesn't require more than two drives?

Comment: I suppose a [checksumming FS, like ZFS](https://github.com/zfsonlinux/zfs/wiki/Checksums), could detect certain silent block errors even on a single disk. ZFS does a lot of more complex processing than a typical RAID controller can, because it operates at a higher level, and can ensure integrity via many different means. It should not be too taxing for a modern desktop / server CPU, though. It's reasonable well supported under Linux, and is first-class FS under FreeBSD. (Just don't enable file deduplication, unless you are sure you know what you are doing.)

Comment: ZFS can detect such errors with only a single disk, but needs at least a mirror drive (or raid-z[123]) to correct them -- that's one of the reasons why it's better to give ZFS the raw drives rather than layer it on top of HW or SW RAID.  i.e. give it JBOD, not RAID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAID1 doesn't write any additional integrity data. So it's unable to detect when a disk has silently corrupted data, except via comparing both copies. Even then, it has no way to know which copy (if any) is correct.

RAID1 handles full-disk failure and can correct *non*-silent data corruption, where the drive signals the error by reporting an unreadable sector (which will be read from the other disk, and then written back to unreadable disk).

This all assumes data made it correctly to disks in the first place; e.g., a machine with bad RAM might corrupt data before its send to mdraid to write, in which case the bad data would be written to both disks.

Comment: This appears to be the case, thank you. Can you assume what would happen if I were to open an image file that has two different copies on both disks, though? Would it just randomly open one? Could I somehow inspect both files and delete the damaged one to rebuild the correct file on both drives? Or is there another solution that encompasses such data errors?

Comment: @Prototype700 Probably best to presume each sector just comes from a random disk (reality is it depends on a bunch of factors, to try to optimize I/O and of course changes from kernel version to kernel version). There are approaches to deal with silent data corruption: e.g., btrfs stores checksums and would notice (and I believe try the other disk). There are userspace approaches like `par2`. Etc. May well be worth its own question, if you can find a way to make it focused enough